# Difference between time zone IDs using TimeZone and ZoneId classes

Tags: java, java-8

In my program, user can choose a time zone from a list of IDs that I get from `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`. This ID is stored in the DB and later I use `ZoneId.of(String zoneId)` to get the ZoneId Object.

But today while debugging I realized that some IDs generated by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` are not recognized by `ZoneId.of(String zoneId)` and a "java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException" is thrown. For example `ZoneId.of("EAT")` throws an exception.

The `ZoneId` class itself can generate a list of zone IDs using `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. this returns 599 Ids for me but `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` returns 627 IDs.

Can someone please explain the difference to me? Why am I getting 2 different lists of zone IDs?

I use Java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs of ZoneId](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)

> **Use of short zone IDs has been deprecated** in java.util.TimeZone. This
>   map allows the IDs to continue to be used via the `of(String, Map)`
>   factory method.

So you should use a different signature of the same method

```
ZoneId.of("EAT", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)
```

or you can use the full name

```
ZoneId.of("Africa/Addis_Ababa")
```

Comment: thanks for clarification. I just checked and the difference between `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` and `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` are only 28 three digit IDs (EST,HST,MST,ACT,AET,AGT,ART,AST,BET,BST,CAT,CNT,CST,CTT,EAT,ECT,IET,IST,JST,MIT,NET,NST,PLT,PNT,PRT,PST,SST,VST). the rest of the entries are exactly matching.